# Mirror for Fedora core 4 still available?

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to rebuild [ELDK 4.0](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/ELDKRebuilding#Section_3.10.2.), which uses Fedora Core 4 as its base. Can anyone direct me to a mirror that still hosts the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old Fedora releases are kept in http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/, for example [Fedora Core 4](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/4/).